# Vaadin 14.10.10 gives com.vaadin.flow.router.NotFoundException: Couldn't find route for '' even though route is defined

Tags: routes, vaadin

- @Route("") is used to define route class yet vaadin throws error:

`com.vaadin.flow.router.NotFoundException: Couldn't find route for ''         at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.handleNavigation(Router.java:277)         at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:232)         at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:198)         at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.initializeUI(Router.java:95)         at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.initializeUIWithRouter(BootstrapHandler.java:1684)         at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.createAndInitUI(BootstrapHandler.java:1677)         at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(BootstrapHandler.java:511)`

using spring boot 2.7.12

- Tried
      `@Route(value = "", layout = TestUI.class)`

  - Also tried
    `    RouteConfiguration routeConfiguration = RouteConfiguration.forApplicationScope();
    routeConfiguration.setAnnotatedRoute(TestRoute.class);``

Comment: Tried a sample project from https://vaadin.com/hello-world-starters#v14 and couldn't reproduce - it loads ok on the empty route. Some more information is needed.